# Sandcastle documentation displays sub-namespaces in a single library as different tree nodes

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, namespaces, sandcastle

I am using Sandcastle for creating C# project library documentation. In my project library, there is one top level namespace and some sub-namespaces depending on folder structure in this project.
For example, if one project library has two namespaces -
MyCompany.Product.FileHelper
MyCompany.Product.FileHelper.Enums

When I see Sandcastle documentation for this project, these two namespaces are shown as different tree nodes but at the *same* level. I want any sub namespace to be shown as a sub-tree.

FYI, current Sandcastle Project Settings - 
[image]

Can anyone please guide how can I show sub-namespaces inside one project library as a sub-tree menu item?

Thank you!